# Is it possible to get the type name of a generic type?

Tags: generics, typescript, reflection, typescript2.0, typename

I have a method signature of `execute<TResult>(): Observable<TResult>`

How do I get the name of the TResult type?

**Example:**

`execute<ViewModel>` --> "ViewModel" is the result I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to get the name of `TResult`, but if you provide the accordingly constructor function you can get the name.

**Declaration:**

```
execute<TResult>(ctor: { new (): TResult }) : <TResult> {
  console.log(ctor.name) //Prints out SomeClass
  return <any>null;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
execute<SomeClass>(SomeClass);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure what happens there. Can you please elaborate on the new(): TResult part? My first guess is that this creates an anonymous constructor-class splatting its properties into a new object that we access via the ctor-parameter.