# How to get Generics in the function when I use typescript

Tags: typescript

When I use Typescript. I have a problem. How to get Generics in the function。

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45IWV.png)

I want to get T's type. Thanks！

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get the type name of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160690/is-it-possible-to-get-the-type-name-of-a-generic-type)

Comment: _"I want to get T's type"_ → You can't. It doesn't exist at runtime.